# how to display unicode docstring by calling help() on idle

Tags: python, macos, unicode, python-idle, docstring

When a function is defined in python, triple quotes represent docstring.

But Asian characters used in docstring are not properly displayed on IDLE for MacOS. They are displayed as a unicode string like '\uc778\uc0ac\ud569\ub2c8\ub2e4'.

On Windows or Linux, they are properly displayed. However, on Terminal shell in MacOS, the docstring made up of Asian characters are properly displayed. What the he**.

I think there may be a bug in tcl/tk. What should I do to represent Asian strings for docstring? I'm programming in python 3.6.3.

Thanks, everyone.

Comment: Triple quotes are only needed for multi-line docstrings.  Aside from that, what do you see when displaying a docstring?  BMP (`\unnnn') chars should either display or be represented by a substitute char.  In any case, this is controlled by tk interacting with the OS.  What tcl/tk are you using?  `Help` => `About IDLE` will show you.  If you use the python.exe binary from python.org, you should use the latest 8.5.x tcl/tk available from ActiveState.  See `https://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/`.

Comment: Thank you, Terry. I installed latest version of ActiveTcl. But Python 3.6.3 doesn't recognize Tcl/Tk. On IDLE, the following message still appears. WARNING: The version of Tcl/Tk (8.5.9) in use may be unstable.
Visit http://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/ for current information.

Comment: All I can say is to **carefully** re-read the instructions on the page above about how Python find a tcl/tk.  I do not have a Mac.

Comment: Thank you. But what I'm telling you is Python can't recognize ActiveState's latest version of Tcl, 8.6.6, though it has been installed properly. I reverted it to an older version, 8.5.18. So the problem I said remains unsolved. Anyway, thank you again.

Comment: I said above 'you should use the latest 8.5.x tcl/tk available', because  `python.org/download/mac/tcltk` explains that macOS will only link python.exe compiled for 8.5 with 8.5.  Tcl/tk 8.6 apparently has several bug fixes especially for maxOS and Python 3.7.0 will be compiled to use (and require) some 8.6.x.  I do not believe that is true yet for the currently available 3.7.0a2.

Comment: Thank you, again. I got what you said. Currently, there's no workaround for the bug, I think.

Answer (score 0):

See if you could use `__doc__` attribute.

```
>>> def func(): 
        """ Return 인사합니다 """
        pass

>>> func.__doc__
' Return 인사합니다 '
```

**Edit**: I tried `help(func)` on Windows 10:

```
>>> help(func)
Help on function func in module __main__:

func()
    Return \uc778\uc0ac\ud569\ub2c8\ub2e4
```

I could print it right with the escape character `u` prefixed to it:

```
>>> print(u'\uc778\uc0ac\ud569\ub2c8\ub2e4')
인사합니다
```

But I got the `docstring` as is on Linux:

```
>>> help(func)
    Help on function func in module __main__:

    func()
        Return 인사합니다
```

Comment: I got the right string display for __doc__. I had the problem displaying docstring by calling help() on MacOS IDLE. I got the unicode string like \uxxxx instead of Asian characters.